# Replying to Gmail thread sends email to myself

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#replybody-options

When **following up** an email given there's no response after the initial email, `reply()` goes to myself, given I'm the one who sent the last email.

So for example, client A sends email to client B. Client A runs script below and reply goes to client A, but it should go to client B as it's only following up since there was no initial reply from B. At least that's how it goes in Gmail interface. I want to send a *follow up*.

I could run a separate sendmail, but that'll start a new thread unless you can [specify the in-reply-to header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924048/how-to-specify-in-reply-to-header-in-sendemail) or the user has responded to the existing thread, which they have not in my case.

Example code:

```
 message.reply("incapable of HTML", {
   htmlBody: "<b>some HTML body text</b>",
   replyTo: theirEmailAddress,
 });
```

However, replyTo actually just specifies the reply-to part of the email being sent, so the response that we receive. It has nothing to do with the actual `to` field aka recipient.

If I do `replyAll`, then the header for the email is:

```
from: me@me.com
to: them@them.com
cc: me@me.com
```

So from that, I get a bunch of emails from myself. I tried specifying cc as none but that didn't change the `cc` field.

```
threads[0].replyAll("Just wanted to follow up and see if you got my last email.", {
htmlBody: followUpText,
cc: null,
});
```

How do I follow up an email, and send it to the original recipient of the last email?

Comment: @Desire Let me clarify. Send an email from A to B. Then run the script on A's account.

Comment: I've encountered this issue, in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969454/reply-to-a-gmailthread#comment80775264_45969454). I've used [getMessages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getmessages) and [getTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getTo()) to get the email of a specific thread. You can now filter it so that you won't reply to your own email. hope this helps.

Comment: @Desire Ignore that part. That was part of an example from the documentation to show the types of objects. I adjusted the code.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot thanks but there's only 1 email in the thread in my example, so the attached SO post is not the same as mine. There is no previous correspondence from B. There are no other messages. A sends B an email. A runs the script above and he gets the email in inbox, but I want it to just go to B - as that's what a follow up is. You send a follow up when someone forget to respond, to bump it back to the top of their inbox.

Comment: @User Did you find a solution? I've got exactly the same issue and I kind of want to pull my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated.**
If the you have initiate the message & not received a reply, you'll probably have to use [`GmailApp.search()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery) to find it in the sent items.  Once you have the message, you can then mimic the behaviour of the Gmail UI with [`message.forward()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forward(String,Object)). Note that you can't modify the text body of the email with `message.forward()`, but you can set the `htmlBody` in the options object.

e.g.

```
  var unanswered = GmailApp.search('subject:"unanswered" in:sent');
  var messages = unanswered[0].getMessages();
  var lastMsg = messages[messages.length - 1]; // get the last message in the thread, just in case you have sent multiple reminders with different conent
  // set your followup text. 
  // + Note that message.forward() doesn't append the thread to the reply, so you'll have to do this yourself
  var followupHTML = '<p>Your followup message.</p><div class="gmail_quote">' + lastMsg.getBody() + '</div>';
  lastMsg.forward(lastMsg.getTo(), {subject: lastMsg.getSubject(), htmlBody: "<p><b>forwarded</b></p>" + followupHTML});
```

Otherwise, for threads that are present in the inbox, you can use something like these:
Check the most recent & use `message.forward()` as above is you are the sender, otherwise, just reply.

```
  var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
  var messages = firstThread.getMessages();
  var lastMsg = messages[messages.length - 1]; // get the last message in the thread
  // set your followup text. 
  // + Note that message.reply() & message.forward()` don't append the thread to the reply, so you'll have to do this yourself -- both text & HTML
  var followupText = "Your followup text.\n" + (lastMsg.getPlainBody()).replace(/^/gm, "> ");
  var followupHTML = '<p>Your followup message.</p><div class="gmail_quote">' + (lastMsg.getBody()) + '</div>'
  var email_re = new RegExp(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), "i");
  if(email_re.test(lastMsg.getFrom())){ 
    lastMsg.forward(lastMsg.getTo(), {lastMsg.getSubject(), htmlBody: followupHTML});
  }
  else{
    lastMsg.reply(followupText, {htmlBody: followupHTML});
  }
```

Alternatively, traverse the thread & find the most recent sender that's not you & reply to that email.

```
  var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
  var messages = firstThread.getMessages();
  var followupText = "Your followup text.";
  var email_re = new RegExp(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), "i");
  var mIdx = messages.length - 1; // last message index
  // walk backward through the thread & return the array index of the most recent sender that's not you
  while(email_re.test(messages[mIdx].getFrom())){ --mIdx;  }
  // now, just reply
  messages[mIdx].reply(followupText);
```

One thing that i tripped over in my testing was the [quota limit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) on the size of the reply email, so some circumspection is needed when including the message body in your response text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right. The main purpose of the script is actually for this to run _only_ in that case. The main problem with `sendEmail` is that it starts a new thread, rather than appending to the existing.

Comment: Understood.  I've provided a second example that will preserve the thread by locating the most recent email sent by someone other then you.  Interestingly, the first method broke the thread for the account running the script, but not for the B party.

Comment: Let me say it again, there are NO other senders other than me. None. From the OP: `So for example, client A sends email to client B. Client A runs script below and reply goes to client A, but it should go to client B as it's only following up since there was no initial reply from B`

Comment: I'm not certain that you will be able to retrieve the unanswered email using `getInboxThreads()` if there's only one item in the thread that lives in sent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but I was searching for an answer to this and am adding in case anyone else is searching and comes across this. I don't know if this is a new option or was always there but this is what I found to solve this issue of who recipient is, or ability to change recipient in a Reply to a thread:

Problem: I send an email to a recipient, then send another one but want to keep it in the same thread so the only way to do it is through Reply, but Reply will reply to the Sender (rightly so). In this case where I was the sender and received no reply, the Reply then is seens as a reply to my email which causes my email to be used (the original sender) which is not correct. I want it to be sent to the original recipient. Oddly with gmail UI it is smart enough to know and will automatically Reply to the original person when you click Reply in the UI. But using the script app it is not as smart and will Reply to sender which in this scenario is the original poster and not the original receiver. This is kind of like sending an email then sending another "bump" email to same person when you don't get a reply. or just sending another followup email without waiting for a reply.

Anyway, I found you can create a draft reply to send, update the draft, then send it.
So something like this (in this case there is only 1 message in thread):

```
var thread = GmailApp.search("in:sent subject:" + subject, 0, 1);
var msgs = thread[i].getMessages();
var thedraft = msgs[0].createDraftReply("Doesnt matter what goes here",
  {
     htmlBody:"the email message for the body",
  }
);
       
thedraft.update(<recipientEmail>, <subject>, <message>); 
thedraft.send(); // if want to auto send. leave out to manually send
```

You can grab the subject and message from the originally created draft to reuse and just change the recipient email in the 1st argument. I tested this and now when it blindly grabs the Sender email I can override it to use the actual original email recipient.

I hope this helps anyone who is struggling with this same issue of replying to a thread in this particular scenario.