# How to specify in-reply-to header in sendEmail()?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options

Looking to specify the `in-reply-to` header of an email I'm sending. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Was looking for this one myself, but concluded it's not possible.  What nut are you trying to crack?  When i looked at my problem differently i came up with a solution that didn't need to set the `in-reply-to` header.

Comment: @DeanRansevycz trying to follow up in the same thread, where a recipient has not yet responded. Gmail says either they need to respond, or you need to use that header.

Comment: Does the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896403/replying-to-gmail-thread-sends-email-to-myself/46923961#46923961 help?